# In Shrek 2 when they drink the potion, we don't see Dragon... but why wasn't she invited with Donkey?

Tags: disney, shrek

From the characters' point of view (in-universe) what is the justification for the decision to cut her out from the event? I mean, Donkey gets invited and on his invitation there is no 'with a +1'? Poor Dragon, I imagine her being so sad like "oh no, hon, you're going on a long trip and I'm not invited? :c" and she would miss him being gone for so long (yeah she's affectionate).

Not to mention that would be EXTREMELY rude of the king & queen not to invite specifically this one friend of their daughter. Especially that friend they treated kinda rudely from the start despite the fact she later proven herself to be a good friend to the princess.

Out of universe, I've read Dragon was supposed to be a unicorn-pegasus while Donkey was a steed (but who are they trying to fool, being a Dragon is already being perfect) but they didn't want her to be the cheat card of the rescue party.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  I've taken the liberty of moving the out-of-story part, which isn't what you're asking, to the end so the question is more prominent.

Comment: In universe, Dragon was pregnant and she agreed with Donkey he needs a vacation, because he was going stir-crazy. Besides, Shrek is his friend, not hers. She just wanted him out of house for a while. So she could deal with pregnancy without Donkey being his intense self all the time. Basically, a last vacation in Vegas before you settle down and raise a family for Donkey. Only  after he gets in trouble, she gets involved.


Would be my guess, but I'll wait for somebody to give proper answer.